# Why is it so hard to implement Bitlocker style disk / partition encryption in Linux?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, encryption, swap, cryptswap

I am a transplant from world of Windows and want to learn linux, so am getting started with Ubuntu 20.04. I initially started with setting up a dual boot option. As I started to seriously consider using Ubuntu more, I realized I don't have disk level encryption enabled. After spending a few days searching for a solution I realized there is no easy way to do it, without enabling it at install time. Since this is my traveling laptop, having encryption at disk level is critical for me.

When I compare this to Bitlocker in Windows it just seems to be much more complex. So my question are:

1. What is it about Ubuntu / Linux that makes the whole disk encryption more complex than in Windows.
2. How do most of you use linux - with or without encryption? If the later then how do you protect data on your disk?

Comment: I'm not sure about the "unbelievably complex" part.  For example, you mixed up your problem of encryption with swap file size.  If you had known about its size beforehand, then you would have gotten it right from the beginning.  On the other hand, I don't think Windows allows you to change the swap file easily.  So, Windows appears easier only because it doesn't let you configure as many things.  (BTW, more recent versions of Ubuntu use a [swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04) instead of a swap partition, I think.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, Linux != Ubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever technically ubuntu is a linux distro

Comment: I think @mike probably meant to say Windows ≠ Ubuntu.  It makes more sense in the context of the question.  OP, why would you create a swap partition with full disk encryption? Ubuntu will use a swap file which is decidedly better for disk space reasons and the size is also dynamic. A swap file will also rest inside the encrypted file system. If you have an unencrypted swap partition, you are kind of throwing away the benefits of whole disk encryption because someone with access to your device can obtain info from your swap.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is not a question, it's a "rant in disguise"

Comment: @Nmath You are correct but it should be noted you can in fact create an encrypted swap partition - the only problem is it can not be used for hibernation or hybrid-sleep.

Comment: @Ray I installed the latest version 20.04, it's still creating an LV for Swap. It didn't give me an option to change the size during installation. I tried following some suggestions on changing the size but ended up breaking the installation, so ended up redoing it. Agree swap size and encryption are separate issues, with encryption being the main issue for me. I mentioned them both together as they resulted from the same action of installing the OS with encryption enabled.

Comment: @Aztek I suggest you move to a swap file and throw away the whole swap partition idea.  As for the other comment about this being a "rant in disguise", it's probably true.  And you should focus on the one problem (i.e., encryption) and not bring in unrelated problems as that will just overwhelm you.

Answer (score 2):

I find encryption on Windows way more complex. On Linux you can do encryption in many many different ways and you can do it fairly trivially. Encrypting your whole OS (wherein you have your /home directory on the same partition as root) is basically a 2 minute process - you just create a blank partition, setup LUKS on it, mount it, then install to it. The only caveat in this situation is you'll need /boot to be separate.

A better way to do it though is to create a separate partition for /home or for your own personal user account [/home/whoever] and mount that at login with PAM - that way you can boot the machine without needing a password or key at boot time to mount root, and your encrypted home will be transparently mounted when you log in, and closed and re-encrypted when you log out.

But there's many many options in Linux and how you lay out partitions and volumes and which are encrypted and how is extremely flexible and you can tweak things to fit your needs. There's also options like using ZFS which has native encryption options.

Just a note - this is not a well formatted question and will definitely be flagged by someone; which is a policy I don't personally agree with but just be aware asking for opinions or comparisons is something Stack/Ask doesn't like - try and find a forum.

Comment: I followed the process of self-creating encrypted partition to install to it. But after the install there were a bunch of additional steps that had to be done. I could just follow them blindly but I am not keen on just getting it over with and want to understand what and why before doing anything. That's what drew me towards the higher complexity comment. You are mixing versatility with complexity. It is trivially easy to encrypt whole drive / partitions on windows, whether done at or after install. On Linux you get more flexibility, but it's harder for newbies like me to get it going.

Comment: Actually if you want whole drive encryption on Linux at install time it's essentially the same as on Windows - the difference being some installers don't do this for you.

Re: versatility vs complexity; you don't realize how complex drive encryption on Windows really is. You need a variety of things for it to work: keys inserted into Secure Boot, signed bootloaders, a secondary boot/recovery partition, etc. If any part of this breaks then you basically loose your data. Linux doesn't need all this and there are multiple recovery options. Play with Linux encryption a bit more and you'll get it